# Xamarin.Forms Android app crashing on splash screen of Android 12

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-12, androidsdk31

I am currently testing my app with VS 2019. Works fine with android devices lower than android 12 but crashes on devices => android 12.I updated android target framework to Android 12. Application that is being deployed on Android 12 crashes on the splash screen without throwing any errors, exception or activating any debugger in App.xaml.cs, SplashActivity.cs or any other file that supposed to be called. I tried all the possible changes in android manifest, mainActivity and splashActivity but it didn't work. Versions **6.4.0 of MVVMCross.Forms** and **4.8.0.1821 of Xamarin.forms** are both used in my application. I uploaded the app to the Play Store for internal testing, and while it functions on all devices, Android 12 devices experience splashing crashes.
I'm using **VS 2019**, Android **SDK 31** and **Android JDK 11**.
I am getting a similar crash in of one my other app as well. Can you please guide me ? I checked but I did not find anything on this.

Comment: What is the error in `logcat`?

Comment: You need to paste in a log so we can check, if you are unable to see it in Visual Studio, Fire up the Android Studio logcat and check.

Comment: Android provides new API for the splash screen on Android 12. Here is the related doc, you could refer to: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate#java. And there is a similar issue, you can check it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6517).